# Paste all strings stored in a vector into a single string, this for each string vectors in a list

Tags: r

This is the begining of the sample code :

```
library(stringr)

Sentences_vector1 <- as.data.frame(rbind("toto a titi", "tata c m tztz itutu", "toto z titi l k tutu h tyty"), stringsAsFactors=F)
Sentences_vector2 <- as.data.frame(rbind("toto a titi", "tata c m tztz itutu", "toto z titi l k tutu h tyty"), stringsAsFactors=F)
Sentences_vectors <- cbind(Sentences_vector1, Sentences_vector2)

List_with_diff_nb_strings = str_match_all(Sentences_vectors$V1, "[a-zA-Z]{2,}")
```

And now, I'm trying to paste all strings stored in a vector into a single string, this for each string vectors in a list. Please note that the vectors have different lengths.

```
List_concacenated_strings = sapply(List_with_diff_nb_strings,function (x) base::paste(x, sep = " "))
```

Thus, I would like to get a result with a content similar as this one :

```
list(c("toto titi"), c("tata tztz tutu"), c("toto titi tutu tyty"))
```

... but it doesn't work since I cannot specify the columns as their numbers are different for each line (character vectors with different lengths) of the list.

Maybe it's due to the fact that in my true R code, the command :

```
str(List_with_diff_nb_strings[[3]])
```

returns :

```
chr [1:4, 1] "toto" "titi" "tutu" "tyty"
```

instead of a "simple" vector like this :

```
chr [1:4] "toto" "titi" "tutu" "tyty"
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: From which package is `str_match_all()`? Please edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43370511/edit

Comment: Done. I was "stringr" Library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the respective line of code with the following:

```
List_concacenated_strings = as.list(sapply(List_with_diff_nb_strings,function (x) base::paste(x, sep = " ",collapse=" ")))
```

And you get your desired output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "toto titi"

[[2]]
[1] "tata tztz tutu"

[[3]]
[1] "toto titi tutu tyty"
```

P.S.: This should be on Stack Overflow